# How to set database number for redis, when using redis sentinel

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel

I have a redis cluster of **1 master, 1 slave and 3 redis sentinel** and springboot application connecting to redis through sentinel.

Application is able to talk to redis through redis sentinel. as we know by default redis instance has 16 databases numbered from 0 - 15, by default connections are made to db0, but in my project i need to connect to db4, because there are other projects which are using 0, 1, 2 etc db4 is assigned to my project.

Jedisconnection factory is being used in the project and i tried setting db from redis properties have a look at the code below

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
spring.redis.password=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=localhost:26379,localhost:26380,localhost:26381
spring.redis.database=4
```

```
public class RedisConfig {

    @Autowired
    private RedisProperties redisProperties;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisSentinelConfiguration redisSentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration();
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setDatabase(redisProperties.getDatabase());
        redisSentinelConfiguration.master(redisProperties.getSentinel().getMaster());
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setPassword(redisProperties.getPassword());
        for(String node : redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes()) {
            String[] props = node.split(":");
            redisSentinelConfiguration.sentinel(props[0], Integer.parseInt(props[1]));
        }
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisSentinelConfiguration);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setDatabase(redisProperties.getDatabase());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate() {
        StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
        stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return stringRedisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Even after doing this, the connection getting created here is using db0.

**Moreover the setDatabase() method of jedisConnectionFactory is showing deprecated.**

Please help me with the correct way of doing this, if my approach is right then when am i making mistake.

**Note: Without redis sentinel configuration i could achieve connection to specific db4 by setting the database in jedisConeectionFactory.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue, by having spring properties:

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
spring.redis.password=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=localhost:26379,localhost:26380,localhost:26381
spring.redis.database=4
```

and below config

```
public class RedisConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private RedisProperties redisProperties;

    public RedisConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisSentinelConfiguration redisSentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration();
        redisSentinelConfiguration.master(this.redisProperties.getSentinel().getMaster());
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setPassword(this.redisProperties.getPassword());
        Iterator var2 = this.redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes().iterator();

        while(var2.hasNext()) {
            String node = (String)var2.next();
            String[] props = node.split(":");
            redisSentinelConfiguration.sentinel(props[0], Integer.parseInt(props[1]));
        }

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisSentinelConfiguration);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setDatabase(this.redisProperties.getDatabase());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate() {
        StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
        stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(this.jedisConnectionFactory());
        return stringRedisTemplate;
    }
}
```